# Perl Threads faster than Sequentially processing?

Tags: perl, performance

Just wanted to ask whether it's true that parallel processing is faster than sequentially processing.
I've always thought that parallel processing is faster, so therefore, I did an experiment.
I benchmarked my scripts and found out that after doing a bunch of

```
sub add{

    for ($x=0; $x<=200000; $x++){
        $data[$x] = $x/($x+2);
    }

}
```

threading seems to be slower by about 0.5 CPU secs on average. Is this normal or is it really true that sequentially processing is faster?

Comment: I hate to say this, but... you didn't actually post your full code, so it's quite possible from our point of view that you didn't quite partition your task right, or that there was a bottleneck somewhere else. Two sufficiently time-consuming, CPU-limited tasks truly running in parallel (i.e. a multi-core system) will of course be faster than running the same two sequentially.

Comment: So if the processes are running from a single-core system, parallel really does not speed up the processing matter am I right? And assuming that if I do not know whether the client is running a single or multi core system, which way of processing would you recommend that, as a developer, you think is faster

Comment: In ideal circumstances, both methods would result in the task taking the same amount of time. Threading in a single core context is more suited to things like loading screens, where you want to load files in the background, but show a low fps (possibly animated) screen simultaneously.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whether parallel vs. sequential processing is better is highly task-dependent and you've already done the right thing:  You benchmarked both and determined for your task (the one you benchmarked, not necessarily the one you actually want to do) which one is faster.

As a general rule, on a single processor, sequential processing tends to be better for tasks which are CPU-bound, because if you have two tasks each needing five seconds of CPU time to complete, then you'll need ten seconds of CPU time regardless of whether you do them sequentially or in parallel.  Setting up multiple threads/processes will, therefore, provide no benefit, but it will create additional task-switching overhead while also preventing you from having *any* results until *all* results are available.

CPU-bound tasks on a multi-processor system tend to do better when run in parallel, provided that they can run independently of each other.  If not, or if you're using a language/threading model/IPC model/etc. which forces all tasks to run on the same processor, then see "on a single processor" above.

Parallel processing is generally better for tasks which are I/O-bound, regardless of the number of processors available, because CPUs are fast and I/O is slow, so working in parallel allows one task to process its data while the other is waiting for I/O operations to complete.  (This is why `make -j2` tends to be significantly faster than a plain `make`, even on single-processor machines.)

But, again, these are all generalities and all have cases where they'll be incorrect.  Only benchmarking will reveal the truth with certainty.

Answer (score 7):

Perl threads are an extreme suck. You are better off in every case forking several processes.

When you create a new thread in perl, it does the following:

- Make a copy - yes, a real copy - of every single perl data structure in scope, including those belonging to modules you didn't write
- Start up what is almost a new, independent instance of perl in a new OS thread

If you then want to share anything (as it has now copied everything) you have to use the share function in the threads module. This is incredibly sucky, as it replaces your variable, with some tie() nonsense, which adds much-too-fine-grained locking around it to prevent concurrent access. Accessing a shared variable then causes a massive amount of implicit locking, and is incredibly slow.

So in short, perl threads:

- Take a long time to start
- waste loads of memory
- Cannot share data efficiently anyway.

You are much better off with fork(), which does not copy every variable (the kernel does copy-on-write) unless you're on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to assume that in a single CPU core system, parallel processing will be faster.

Consider this png example:
[image]

The red and blue lines at the top represent two tasks running sequentially on a single core.

The alternate red and blue lines at the bottom represent two task running in parallel on a single core.

Comment: But seeing that I may be parsing 5-6 log files at a go and using different subs, which one would be the faster way then.

Comment: @robobooga: Do you actually need a performance boost? And if this is reading logfiles... might disk access be the bottleneck anyway?

Comment: There's no harm in using threads on the off chance that a client might have more than one CPU core. If there's a way of determining the CPU core/thread count, then you can have your program only use threads if there is more than one physical core.

Comment: I really need to squeeze out as much speed as possible as I am parsing logs for a real time server and I wish to have the anomalies alerted as soon as possible. as for the case of disk access, my experiment deals only with arithmetric processes, and yet it's slower. Was wondering if the overhead is the one that is causing the slowness